# Approaches i can follow to automate creating sub-folders when we add a root folder inside our sharepoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, development, document-library, flow

I am working on a online document library inside out modern team site. and i want to automate the following:-

1- when a user create a root folder inside the document library, to create some sub-folders with 3 hierarchy.

2- for example if a user add a root folder named "HR", to have these sub-folders automatically created:-

```
HR
  - Private
       -For Employees
       -Confidential
       -Procedures
          -Employees
          -External Users

  - Public
       -For customers
       -For suppliers
```

Now if i were inside SP 2010 or SP 2013, i would simply create a server-side event receiver and do the work. but in SP online creating remote event receivers are not working for me, especially i am unable to debug them using azure service bus (which was deprecated). so i am asking if i can achieve what i am looking using sharepoint workflow 2013 or flow or another approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is through **Microsoft Flow**.

You can use "*item creation*" as trigger, using a if condition to check if the element is a folder and the item is created in a specific folder, then if both condition are verified you can add as many "Folder creation" actions you want to build the subfolders tree.

See the below example:

[image]

Important notes:

- Folder name rely on your istance language (with my italian settings "Shared documents" corresponds to "Documenti condivisi")
- If you want to create a folder with subfolders you can skip that parent creation, creating a subfolder automatically add the parent folder if it is missing
- With MS Flows you can manage permission settings on folders (add an action "Set permission to folder")